# DRF nested through model serialization filtering

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Each of my models is inherited from the base model, which contains the `publishing_status`  field that helps me control whether or not the object is included in the returned data.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class PublishingStatus(models.TextChoices):
        ACCEPTED = 'accepted', 'Accepted'
        REJECTED = 'rejected', 'Rejected'

    publishing_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=9,
        choices=PublishingStatus.choices,
        default=PublishingStatus.DRAFT,
        help_text="Publishing status represents the state of the object. By default it is 'draft'"
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Here are two models `Word` and `Homonym` they both inherit from `BaseModel`:

```
class Word(BaseModel):
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    homonyms = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Homonym', through_fields=('homonym', 'word'))


class Homonym(BaseModel):
    homonym = models.ForeignKey(Word, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="homonyms")
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="word_homonyms")
```

Homonyms are basically words too, so I have self-reference here, but through the model `Homonym` so that I could control these relationships to be public or not for my website.

Then follow the serializers and probably the solution should be passed here:

```
class HomonymSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Homonym
        fields = '__all__'


class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    homonyms = HomonymSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Question**: Currently, all homonyms are displayed, regardless of whether they are accepted or not. How can I restrict the nested serializer to include only homonyms with the `publishing_status="accepted"`?

Here is my view:

```
class WordRetrieveView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = WordSerializer
    queryset = Word.objects.all().filter(publishing_status='accepted')
```

---

My current solution is to define the `homonyms` field as `SerializerMethodField()` and filter the queryset here (I have a feeling that this is not the best way and not django way):

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        homonyms = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        
        class Meta:
            model = Word
            fields = '__all__'

        @staticmethod
        def get_homonyms(obj):
            homonyms = Homonym.objects.all().filter(publishing_status='accepted', homonym_id=obj.id)
            return [HomonymSerializer(Word.objects.get(id=h.homonym_id)).data for h in homonyms]
```

---

**bdbd**s approach

Removed `HomonymSerializer`
Removed `get_homonyms` method of `WordSerializer`

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):            
        class Meta:
            model = Word
            fields = '__all__'

class WordRetrieveView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = WordSerializer
    queryset = Word.objects.all().filter(publishing_status='accepted').prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('homonyms', queryset=Homonym.objects.filter(publishing_status='accepted'))
    )
```

Comment: Try setting the queryset to this: `Word.objects.filter(publishing_status='accepted')`

Answer (score 0):

Your main queryset will only affect the results returned by `Word`, and not the related homonyms. So you also need to apply the same filter on the related objects, if you want only a certain subset to be returned.

In this case it should be enough to just change your queryset to:

```
Word.objects.filter(publishing_status='accepted').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('homonyms', queryset=Homonym.objects.filter(publishing_status='accepted'))
)
```

This will get all the `Word`s that are accepted, as well as get any related homonyms per word that are accepted as well.

Comment: I got `prefetch_related() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'` But then I tried your approach using `from django.db.models import Prefetch` and I still get all Homonyms that have publishing status "rejected"

Comment: Yes you're right it should use `Prefetch`. Updated my answer

Comment: From you serializer method approach: `Homonym.objects.all().filter(publishing_status='accepted', homonym_id=obj.id)` -- `obj.id` here should be filtered with `word_id` right?.

Comment: You might have to also filter if the actual word/homonym that is linked in the through table is also accepted (not just the relation), like: `Homonym.objects.filter(publishing_status='accepted', homonym__publishing_status='accepted')`

Comment: It does not work, I still get all Homonyms. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Do you mind updating your question with all the latest code you have? And if possible, some sample data

Comment: Also based on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields), the order of through fields is important, so I'm not totally sure if you intended to use `through_fields=('homonym', 'word')` instead of `through_fields=('word', 'homonym').` `word` should be the source object and `homonym` the target right?